# How do I add text after a string value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to add County Court after the string value for the courtname. In my xsl I am using a variable vCourtORI to get the court name in the referring xml document. 
I need to add County Court after the Text on this line

`<xsl:value-of select="$values[@type='CountyName']/Text"/>`

How do I do this. My xslt is displaying the Court Name but I want to add County Court after the name.

Desired output

`<nc:OrganizationName>Ramsey County Court</nc:OrganizationName>`

Current output

`<nc:OrganizationName>Ramsey</nc:OrganizationName>`

sample xml document

```
xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67084429" xmlns="">
    <Case InternalID="1616099249" ID="10475952" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <Court>
            <CourtName>Ramsey Criminal Suburban</CourtName>
            <CourtNCIC>MN062105J</CourtNCIC>
        </Court>
</Integration>
```

Refering xm document for the Court name using CourtNCIC number

```
<EnumerationValue code="MN062105J">
    <Text>Ramsey Criminal Suburban</Text>
    <AssociatedValue type="CountyName">
      <Text>Ramsey</Text>
    </AssociatedValue>
</EnumerationValue>
```

xsl code

```
    <xsl:template name="Court">
<Court>
<nc:StreetFullText>
    <xsl:variable name="vCourtORI">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/Court/CourtNCIC"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="values" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\CourtXML\SimpleTypes\CourtLocationTextType.xml'))/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code=$vCourtORI]/AssociatedValue"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$values[@type='CountyName']/Text"/> 
</nc:StreetFullText>
</Court>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `xslt:text` tag after your value-of with the county name.

```
<xsl:text> Country Court</xsl:text>
```